# Dragging Bar Button Item to Navigation Controller fails

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am following a tutorial on Udemy about Navigation Controllers.

The instructions are to drag a Navigation Controller onto the storyboard, and then drag and drop a Bar Button Item on the right of its navigation bar to segue to another view controller.

However, when I drag the Bar Button Item to its would-be position on the navigation bar, no drop-zone gets highlighted, and the button gets added to a random tab at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried finding references to this problem but all solutions are programmatic and given the wysiwyg nature of iOS development I would like to solve it through XCode UI.

Is there some setup I must change or is this an XCode 7 discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a ViewController and then in `Editor -> Embed in -> NavigationController`. Then it should work.

Comment: I still cannot drop Bar Button Items to the top navigation bar @mikle94

Comment: Do you drag it to navigationBar into created viewController or NavigationController? You should drag in to your VC.

Comment: The video instructions are to drag it into the navigation bar of the Root View Controller, as depicted here: http://imgur.com/CjCsFnE

Comment: figured it out, check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by dragging the `Bar Button Item` into the Document Outline, below `Root View Controller`.

This automatically creates `Left Bar Button Items` and `Right Bar Button Items`, which gives you an opportunity to drag the `Item` in the section of the controller you like.